# pagination not working when clicking on page number

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel pagination. When I click on next page or any page number, nothing happens.
**Controller function**

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $articles = Inspector::paginate(15);
    return view('admin.inspector.test', compact('articles'));
}
```

**View file**

```
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sr. No.&nbsp;</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($articles as $article)
                            <tr>
                            <td>{{ $article->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $article->email }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {!! $articles->render() !!}
```

Any help is much appreciated...Thanks...

Comment: what is the error? did u tried to use  `{!!  str_replace('/?', '?', $articles->render()) !!}`

Answer (score -2):

```
public function getIndex()
{
    return view('admin.inspector.test');
}
```

just return view while calling the action. dont send any data from the controller, just load the view, 
when the view loads, fetch the db connection with pagination method. and render the pagination as below

```
<?php $articles = DB::connection('table_name')->where('if any condition')->get(); ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Sr. No.&nbsp;</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($articles as $article)
                                <tr>
                                <td>{{ $article->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $article->email }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {!! $articles->render() !!}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more...If I don't return data with view, how  it supposed to get data from db ...!

Comment: Vote down for your answer

Comment: It is very bad practice to call db connection from view..So this way is not feasible.